# Typescript .length return undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

This issue makes me crazy ...

I have this code :

```
if (control.value==null||control.value == "" || control.value == " " || control.value.length != 5) {
     // do something
}
```

My problem : `control.value.length` always returns 'undefined'.

I try to use a string variable like this but the result is the same.

```
var curVal: string = control.value;
if (curVal==null||curVal== "" || curVal == " " || curVal != 5) {
     // do something
}
```

Where am I wrong ?

*Edit:* Precision : my control.value is not null or empty, I test with the value 59000

This code :

```
console.log(control.value + ' - ' + control.value.length);
```

log this : *59000 - undefined*

**EDIT 2 :** Thank's you, it's solved. The problem was my control.value was a **number** and not a **string**.

Comment: Is the value 59000 a string ?

Comment: You need to provide more code that demonstrates what you're doing.

Comment: 59000 is the value of control.value.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(typeof control.value, control.value, control.value.length);`?

Comment: @Sasxa I logged typeof (control.value) as you say, type is number ... it is why I have this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the type of your input isn't string but number.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="number" [ngFormControl]="ctrl">
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.ctrl = new Control();
    this.ctrl.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(val.length);
    });
  }
}
```

In this case `val.length` returns `undefined` since numbers don't have a `length` attribute.

See this plunkr for more details: https://plnkr.co/edit/5yp5ms9XY5Z3TEE2qYIh?p=preview.

Comment: So you could try this: `val.toString().length`

Comment: If you want to check the number of items. For example: `2` -> `1`, `30` -> `2` and so on...

Comment: I completly do not understand this issu, but when you type: yourObject.toString().length so it works fine. Also when yourObject is a string!

Answer (score 4):

Try Like these

```
String(control.value).length != 5
```

OR

```
control.value.toString().length != 5
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Your answer adds very little to the original question and the answers/comments given.

Answer (score 1):

### In Typescript:

```js
     let a="hello";
     let length=a.toString().length;
     console.log(length);
```

Output: `5`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is this bug on Angular, since version 5.0.0 I think, even when the variable is not a number, I've to convert it to a number to use the '.length' property like below :

```
if (control.value==null||control.value == "" || control.value == " " || +(control.value.length) != 5) {
 // do something
```

It may works, just by adding the sign '+' before your var.length like: `+(var.length)`